# Grouping serial posts in a user feed

Tags: mysql, database-design, grouping, feed

I have a user feed of image posts. Each user can post single images, however, he can repeat the action often. Say, upload several images within an hour.

How do I effectively design the database table so when a user posts multiple images (one by one) within one hour — I can easily group those *serial* posts together, eigher on INSERT or on SELECT?

---

Don't suggest multi-upload form. That's not the case: I've just described the task in more common terms :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's out playground:

```
CREATE TABLE `feed`(
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tm` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp',
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'author id',
  `image` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'posted image filename',
  `group` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'post group',
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
  INDEX(`user_id`),
  INDEX(`tm`,`group`)
  );
```

We'd like to group together posts that are temporally close.

First, declare the wanted granularity: the threshold to temporal proximity:

```
SET @granularity:=60*60;
```

Each row forms a group with group ID matching the row id (it can also be a timestamp):

```
SELECT `g`.`id` AS `group`
FROM `feed` `g`;
```

Each group contains rows that originate from the same user, were posted earlier than the group-former:

```
SELECT `g`.`id` AS `group`, `f`.*
FROM `feed` `g`
    CROSS JOIN `feed` `f`
    ON (`f`.`user_id` = `g`.`user_id` 
        AND `f`.`tm` BETWEEN `g`.`tm`-@granularity AND `g`.`tm`
    )
```

Each row belongs to multiple groups. For each row, we pick the most 'broad' group: it has the biggest rowId

```
SELECT MAX(`g`.`id`) AS `group`, `f`.*
FROM `feed` `g`
    CROSS JOIN `feed` `f`
    ON (`f`.`user_id` = `g`.`user_id` 
        AND `f`.`tm` BETWEEN `g`.`tm`-@granularity AND `g`.`tm`
    )
GROUP BY `f`.`id`
```

The most recently updated group always jumps to the top (if you sort by `group` DESC).
However, if you'd like the groups be persistent (e.g. so items don't move from one group to another), use `MIN` instead of `MAX`:

```
SELECT MIN(`g`.`id`) AS `group`, `f`.*
FROM `feed` `g`
    CROSS JOIN `feed` `f`
    ON (`f`.`user_id` = `g`.`user_id` 
        AND `f`.`tm` BETWEEN `g`.`tm` AND `g`.`tm`+@granularity
    )
GROUP BY `f`.`id`
```

Now, we're going to update the table's `group` column.
First, MySQL can't update the same table you're reading from. Wee need a temporary table.
Second: we only update the rows whose `group` column is NULL, or rows posted later than `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2*@threshold`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `_feedg`
SELECT MAX(`g`.`id`) AS `group`, `f`.`id`
FROM `feed` `g`
    CROSS JOIN `feed` `f`
    ON (`f`.`user_id` = `g`.`user_id` 
        AND `f`.`tm` BETWEEN `g`.`tm`-@granularity AND `g`.`tm`
    )
WHERE `f`.`group` IS NULL 
    OR `f`.`tm` >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2*@granularity)
GROUP BY `f`.`id`;
```

And update the `group` column:

```
UPDATE `feed` `f` CROSS JOIN `_feedg` `g` USING(`id`)
SET `f`.`group` = `g`.`group`;
```

Here's the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be9ce/15

Answer (score 3):

Can you store a timestamp with each post, and then select each item whose timestamp is less than some threshold from the next?

Another idea would be to store both a timestamp and a "group number" with each post.  Before you store a post, execute a `SELECT` to look for posts that were submitted within the last `n` minutes.  If you find one, use the same group number for the new post.  If you don't then increment the group number for the new post.  Then you can select by group number to find the items you want.

Comment: Any column is possible, including timestamp. But then how to select, making 'close' rows stick together?

Comment: Updated.  When you try to solve a problem like this, forget about the computer and database; just think about it logically: how can you "relate" several items together?

Comment: Sure! I'm not sure, however, that's the most efficient one :) If I use your suggestion — then I'll have to use [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542647/grouping-serial-posts-in-a-user-feed) to display the feed

Comment: Most efficient?  Probably not.  Simple, efficient enough, and easy to implement?  Yes.  Also, at least so far, it's the most efficient implementation that's been suggested here.  ;-P

Comment: doing tricky temporal queries isn't always terribly efficient either. It only gets harder when you decide you only want to select the most recent group or three. I like the idea of identify the group of the record before inserting it, but I would store a timestamp too in case the window of opportunity ever needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the data model would look similar this:

[image]

Just be careful to ensure the temporal difference between posts is greater than the resolution of the TIMESTAMP (or be prepared to handle PK violations gracefully).

In a DBMS that supports analytic functions, you can then fairly easily group posts that are temporally close together. For example, Oracle query to group posts (for the given user) that fall within an hour of each other, would look like this:

```
SELECT T.*, SUM(DIFF) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) GROUPING
FROM (
    SELECT
        IMAGE.*,
        CASE
            WHEN TIMESTAMP <= LAG(TIMESTAMP) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP)
                + INTERVAL '1' HOUR
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END DIFF
    FROM IMAGE
    WHERE USER_ID = :user_id
) T;
```

The resulting GROUPING field will identify individual groups of rows whose TIMESTAMP is "close enough". This query is also quite efficient - it's just a range scan on the PK index. You can play with it in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/811df/72).

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support analytic functions, but you should have no trouble doing essentially the same at the application level. Just `SELECT ... ORDER BY TIMESTAMP`, linearly traverse the results and see what's the difference between the current and the previous row.

Comment: Using time difference between rows works only while each user searial posts are not "interrupted" by other user's posts :)

Comment: @o_OTync I'm not sure I understand. This schema enables you to efficiently do a per-user grouping, even when other users are concurrently posting images (there is `WHERE USER_ID = :user_id`). Do you disagree with that premise, or perhaps you need to do something else?

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your query :) Unfortunately, I need MySQL and this won't help :(

Answer (score 1):

Solution by "o_O Tync" won't group items within 1hour if they are added e.g.: 1:00, 1:40, 2:30. Only last two will be grouped.

Here is superfast Mysql solution w/o temp tables and joins (of same table).

```
CREATE TABLE `feed`(
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tm` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp',
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'author id',
  `image` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'posted image filename',
  `group` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'post group',
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
  INDEX(`user_id`),
  INDEX(`tm`,`group`)
  );


SET @granularity:=60*60;
UPDATE feed f CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT
    g.id,
    @id:=COALESCE( IF( ISNULL(@prev_date) OR (user_id!=@prev_user_id) OR NOT(@prev_date-tm BETWEEN 0 AND @granularity), g.id, NULL), @id)
    +least(0, @prev_date:=tm)
    +least(0, @prev_user_id:=user_id) as group_id    
  FROM (SELECT @prev_date:=null, @id:=null, @user_id:=null) r, feed g
  ORDER BY user_id DESC, tm DESC
) z USING (id)
SET f.group = z.group_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02a98/1/0